# Can I force a cast of an object to a identical type in diffefent web reference resource.cs?

Tags: c#, coldfusion

So, I have an app I am working on and I have to call two cold Fusion web services,

```
http://blah/search.cfc and http://blah/asset.cfc
```

which both return a "QueryBean".  I have called them DAM_Search and DAM_Asset.  The QueryBean result is of identical types but they are stored in two directories.

DAM_Search has this class located at 
**project folder\Web References\DAM_Search\Reference.cs** 
and DAM_Asset has the same class located at 
**project folder\Web References\DAM_Asset\Reference.cs**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://wstypes.newatlanta.com")]

public partial class QueryBean {

    private object[] dataField;
    private string[] columnListField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public object[] data {
        get {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string[] columnList {
        get {
            return this.columnListField;
        }
        set {
            this.columnListField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I would like to send the result from this service to a single function that converts the QueryBean to an XML node that I can pass back what ever app that has called it. But when I try and use the function it fails because a DAM_Search.QueryBean is not the same as DAM_Asset.QueryBean.  When I try and cast it

```
private XmlDocument Get_AssetInfo(object qBean)
{
      DAM_Search.QueryBean qBean2 = (DAM_Search.QueryBean)qBean;
```

I get this error message

*Unable to cast object of type 'DAM_Service.DAM_Asset.QueryBean' to type 'DAM_Service.DAM_Search.QueryBean'.*

Is there a way I can force the cast since I know the data type is really the same, or is there a way that I can tell the web service to use the same class reference for the QueryBean class?

Does this make any since to anyone out there?  :-)

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to perform this cast if you cause the object to really be identical in both sides, that is to also have the same type name and assembly name.

What I mean is, you can have a separate DLL that will contain the shared classes like QueryBean. Then reference this project from both services. Now the cast should succeed.

The reason it is failing is because even though the QueryBean class in both projects has exactly the same properties, the .NET Framework doesn't know that since the two types are in completely different assemblies.